# UpdateProgress Control - How to improve its responsiveness?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I'm using the UpdateProgress control in ASP.NET.  My question is simply how do I improve it's responsiveness?  It doesn't consistently show up if at all.  I would use JQuery to simulate the effect but I'm trying to avoid introducing tons of javascript because it's a webforms application.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, how are you approaching it currently? Try using the methods shown here http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/ProgrammingUpdateProgress.aspx and see if you get the same inconsistency.

Comment: I came across this link in my hunting. Check my answer below to see how I resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the inconsistency I set the "DisplayAfter" property to 1 millisecond.  My guess is that the AJAX framework is using some heuristic for determining if the length of time of the request will be sufficiently long enough to display the update progress.  Setting the "DisplayAfter" property must make it deterministic.